# "inverse" value with Polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

Say, I have a dataset in the following DataFrame:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({
    'x':['a','a','b','b'],
    'y':['b','c','c','a'],
    'value':[3,5,1,4]
})
df
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ 3     │
│ a   ┆ c   ┆ 5     │
│ b   ┆ c   ┆ 1     │
│ b   ┆ a   ┆ 4     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

Now, I'd like to add a column to this dataframe that would contain the inverse
value. I define an *inverse* value as `inverse(x, y) == value(y, x)`. E.g., from
the example above, `inverse (a, b) == value(b, a) == 4`.

If `value(y, x)` didn't exist then `inverse(x, y)` would be given the default
value of `0`.

In other words, I'd like to add an `inverse` column such as I'd end up with
something like this:

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ value ┆ inverse │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ 3     ┆ 4       │
│ a   ┆ c   ┆ 5     ┆ 0       │
│ b   ┆ c   ┆ 1     ┆ 0       │
│ b   ┆ a   ┆ 4     ┆ 3       │
└─────┴─────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

Is this doable in an easy and optimal way? Preferably with expressions?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `join` it to itself with aliases and then do `fill_null(0)`.

```
df.join(
    df.select(
        y="x",
        x="y",
        inverse="value"
    ),
    on=["x","y"], how="left"
).fill_null(0)
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ value ┆ inverse │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ str ┆ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ 3     ┆ 4       │
│ a   ┆ c   ┆ 5     ┆ 0       │
│ b   ┆ c   ┆ 1     ┆ 0       │
│ b   ┆ a   ┆ 4     ┆ 3       │
└─────┴─────┴───────┴─────────┘
```